# Modify an object property inside array without altering original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like below

```
myobjects = [
 {
   id: 1,
   images: [
    {imgName: 'image name.jpg',type: ''},
    {imgName: 'image name.jpg',type: ''}
 }
]
```

Now i assign myObj to another variable so that i can make changes to that variable without altering the myObj. e.g:

```
newObjects = [
 {
   id: 1
   images: [
    {imgName: "image name.jpg"},
    {imgName: "image name.jpg"}
   ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
myobjects.map(({id, images}) => ({id, images: images.map(({imgName})=> ({imgName}))}));
```

An example:

```js
let myobjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    images: [
     {imgName: 'image name.jpg',type: ''},
     {imgName: 'image name.jpg',type: ''}
    ]
  }
 ]


const result = myobjects.map(({id, images}) => ({id, images: images.map(({imgName})=> ({imgName}))}));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks. it solved my problem